# Changing the DataTemplate of a TreeView in runtime

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, treeview, itemscontrol

I have a `TreeView` with 3 levels in my WPF application.

Level 1 and level 2 have their own `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Level 3 has its own `DataTemplate`.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level1Template" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level2RedTemplate}">
        <Border Background="Green">
            <TextBlock Text="Level1"/>
        </Border>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level2RedTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level3Template}">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="Level2"/>
        </Border>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level2YellowTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level3Template}">
        <Border Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock Text="Level2"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Level3Template">
        <Border Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="Level3"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            Content="Change Template"
            Click="ChangeTemplate" />

    <TreeView Grid.Row="1"
              Name="tv"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level1Template}"/>
</Grid>
```

It works perfectly until here. **The problem starts**, when I want to change the `DataTemplate` of Level2 items by pressing a button in my window (see figure below).
[image]

I tried to assign a new `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to my `TreeView` from code behind (in the event handler of the button) like this:

```
Private Sub ChangeTemplate()

    CType(tv.ItemTemplate, HierarchicalDataTemplate).ItemTemplate = CType(Me.FindResource("Level2YellowTemplate"), HierarchicalDataTemplate)

End Sub
```

This is not possible, as I get an error, that "as soon as a Template-Object is used (sealed), it cannot be changed."

Is there any way, that I can change this template?

Comment: You should take a look at `DataTemplateSelector`. You will be able to switch from a template to another during runtime.

Comment: @Bob But I think that `DataTemplateSelector` selects the `DataTemplate` based on some properties of my data, is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly. How do you intend to choose your new Template?

Comment: @Bob my data / any property of it doesn't change. I only want to change the template. So in more details: I change the `ItemsSource` (which has the same type as the old `ItemsSource`), and I want a new template for this new source.

Comment: Ok, I don't know if this possible to do that way. But if you really want to follow the MVVM pattern, you'd better rely on your properties to change the DataTemplate => That is exactly the purpose of the MV... So you would create a specific property to switch your Template.

Comment: @Bob Oh perfect, Thank you very much! That sounds promissing, I will try it out, to see if it works as I want. In the meanwhile, you can write it as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helfupful comment from @Bob, I solved the problem like this:

I defined a property in the `UserControl`, where I have the `TreeView`.

I changed the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` of level 1 like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level1Template" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MySelector}">
    <Border Background="Green">
        <TextBlock Text="Level1"/>
    </Border>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I implemented the `MySelector` class and implemented the `Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate` function. Using the `container`, I could access my `UserControl` and its properties.

The `ItemsSource` of my `TreeView` changes when I press a button in my usercontrol. After each change, the `TemplateSelector` is called, and so the template is updated.