# Both 'ItemTemplate' and 'ItemTemplateSelector' are set; 'ItemTemplateSelector' will be ignored

Tags: wpf, treeview, controltemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate, itemtemplateselector

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173382/changing-the-datatemplate-of-a-treeview-in-runtime), I have another question about `TreeView`.

What I already have is a `TreeView`with `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, in which I can change the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` of level2 (like explained in the question and the answer).

What I want now, is to change the look of the expander of the `Treeview`. For this, I have defined a `ControlTemplate` named `ctForTreeViewItem`, and I use it like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ctForTreeViewItem"
                     TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Expander IsExpanded="True"
                  Background="Grey"
                  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                  Foreground="White"
                  BorderThickness="1,1,1,3">
            <Expander.Header>
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                        Name="Bd"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        Grid.Column="1">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                      Name="PART_Header"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </Expander.Header>

            <Expander.Content>
                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" />
            </Expander.Content>

        </Expander>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Level3Template">
        <Border Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="Level3"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level2RedTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level3Template}">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="Level2"/>
        </Border>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level2YellowTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level3Template}">
        <Border Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock Text="Level2"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level1Template" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MySelector}">

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource ctForTreeViewItem}" />
            </Style>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>

        <Border Background="Green">
            <TextBlock Text="Level1"/>
        </Border>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TreeView Grid.Row="1"
          Name="tv"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level1Template}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource ctForTreeViewItem}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

This works for Level1 as expected, so on Level 1, I have `TreeViewItems` with the defined `ControlTemplate` and the Correct `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

However, it doesn't work on Level2, where I have an `ItemTemplateSelector`. At this position, I get this error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 25 : Both 'ItemTemplate' and 'ItemTemplateSelector' are set;  'ItemTemplateSelector' will be ignored.`

- Is there any way, that I can assign a `ControlTemplate` to the `TreeViewItem`s, while keeping the `ItemTemplateSelector`? Or even
- Is there any other way, that I can change the style of the expander of the `TreeView`?

Comment: Have you tried setting ItemTemplateSelector in the TreeViewItem style in your HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Comment: And what does it mean? does it mean that I cannot use them at the same time (like I explained above)?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I also moved the `ItemTemplateSelector` on level1. I had the same error as soon as I defined a `Template` for `ItemContainerStyle` of the `TreeView`.

Comment: Yes, naturally you can't set both Itemtemplate and ItemtemplateSelector. That has nothing to do with ItemContainerStyle. Don't set ItemTemplate. Use the ItemTemplateSelector to select the item template. Also, if you're having the problem with "level 2", what's level 2? Can we see the code for it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett you are right, I wanted to prevent making the question big, by repeating my previous question. Now I editted the question.

Comment: Why are you setting ItemContainerStyle everywhere? You only need to do that once, on the TreeView, unless you want to start giving your child TreeViewItems a *different* style at some level. I only see one treeviewitem control template; did you omit a second one for the sake of brevity?

Comment: @EdPlunkett and i don't set `Itemtemplate` and `ItemtemplateSelector` at the same time. I set `ControlTemplate` and `ItemtemplateSelector` at the same time. At leat that is my intention.

Comment: Yes I actually wanted to have Level1 Expanded, and Level2 Collapsed. I removed them now: I have a ControlTemplate for my TreeView, ItemTemplateSelector for Level1, and No ItemContainerStyle for the levels. And I still have the same error.

Comment: Do you also use the `ControlTemplate`, and you get no errors?

Comment: See update to my answer. Everything was due to problems in your ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TreeViewItem ControlTemplate is broken. It ignores the data template selector because you [explicitly override that by setting `ContentTemplate` on the `ContentPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence). That's similar to what's causing the (harmless) errors in your debug output stream as well: The level 2 templates inherit an `ItemTemplateSelector` from their ancestors, in the same way that if you set `ItemContainerStyle` once on the `TreeView`, it will be inherited by all children of the treeview unless some intervening child overrides it explicitly. No need to set it more than once. Because the level 2 templates inherit `ItemTemplateSelector` and override it with a different property, you get an error, but it's harmless.

I fixed the control template by changing the ContentPresenter for the Header to match the default TreeViewItem control template: I removed the `Content`, `ContentTemplate`, and `ContentStringFormat` attributes. The `ContentPresenter` has default behavior for all that stuff so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

```
<ContentPresenter 
    ContentSource="Header"
    Name="PART_Header"
    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
    />
```

The template/template selector errors are harmless but I was able to silence them by setting `ItemTemplateSelector` explicitly to null on the level 2 hierarchical data templates:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    x:Key="Level2RedTemplate"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{x:Null}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level3Template}"
    >
    <Border Background="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="Level2"/>
    </Border>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```